# Who should register a service in Consul: application or init system?

Tags: consul, service-discovery

Imagine I have an application which should be registered in Consul. Who should actually do this: the application itself, or whatever initialization system responsible for launching it?

For example, with `systemd` it seems obvious to put the service registration to `ExecStartPost`. On the other hand, it may be better to let the application itself handle this task.

Which one is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually initialization system can't know some specific details of application. So in my opinion application knows much more about its services which it can provide. So they should register in SD system.

For example:

`app1` registered as HTTP APIv1 and APIv2 services,

`app2` registered as HTTP APIv3 service

`app3` registered as only for HTTP Web service

In that case your applications can be more independent from specific initialization systems. eg: `systemd`, `runit`, `ubuntu init` or `docker-related`